# Why is kinetic energy defined as the measure of work an object can do due the virtue of its motion?

Tags: work

Saying that KE=1/2mv^2 holds even when magnitude or direction of force changes, so the expression is valid irrespective of how the body acquires the velocity shouldn't be correct as work done depends on the direction of force relative to the displacement. If displacement and force are perpendicular work down by the object is 0. So how can the expression of kinetic energy hold under any direction of change in force?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

The result is: the *change* in kinetic energy is the work

\begin{eqnarray}
\vect{F} &=& m \vect{a} \\
\vect{F}\cdot {\rm d}\vect{x} &=& m \frac{{\rm d}\vect{v}}{{\rm d}t}\cdot {\rm d}\vect{x} = m  \frac{{\rm d}\vect{v}}{{\rm d}t}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}\vect{x}}{{\rm d}t} {\rm d}t = m {\vect v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}\vect{v}}{{\rm d}t}{\rm d}t\\
\int {\rm d}\vect{x}\cdot\vect{F}&=& m\int{\rm d}t \vect{v}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}\vect{v}}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{1}{2}m\int{\rm d}t~\frac{{\rm d}(\vect{v}\cdot \vect{v})}{{\rm d}t} = \Delta T
\end{eqnarray}

So you have

$$
W = \Delta T
$$

with

$$
T = \frac{1}{2}mv^2
$$

For example if $\vect{F}\perp {\rm d}\vect{x}$ then $W = 0$ and the kinetic energy will not change!

Comment: In the last sentence you probably mean the force to be perpendicular to the displacement, don't you?

Comment: @GennaroTedesco correct, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is a scalar quantity. Velocity is a vector quantity, i.e. it has a direction. Likewise momentum is a vector quantity. Vector quantities can be resolved into components along coordinate lines. Scalar quantities like kinetic energy and potential are just single numbers at any spacetime location. You essentially loose the vector information when you square the velocity vector.

You should be cautioned that the definition you are using in the title is only valid if you measure the work in a "conservative interaction", i.e. one where the energy of the system is not dissipated in an unmeasured manner. You would need to account for any heat or sound when trying to sum up the "work" done in the process of decelerating a moving body.